# Ошибка при подключении RedBean

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Подключаю

```
<?php 
    require "libs/rb.php";
    R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users',
        'root', '' );
?>
```

и он мне выводит ошибку

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\localhost\www\TPL\libs\rb.php on line 3

открываю файл `rb.php`, смотрю на первые строки

```
<?php

namespace RedBeanPHP {

/**
 * RedBean Logging interface.
 * Provides a uniform and convenient logging
 * interface throughout RedBeanPHP.
 *
 * @file    RedBean/Logging.php
 * @author  Gabor de Mooij and the RedBeanPHP Community
 * @license BSD/GPLv2
 *
 * @copyright
 * copyright (c) G.J.G.T. (Gabor) de Mooij and the RedBeanPHP Community
 * This source file is subject to the BSD/GPLv2 License that is bundled
 * with this source code in the file license.txt.
 */
```

третья строка `namespace RedBeanPHP {`

Понять не могу, в чём проблема.

Comment: Неймспейсы появились в РНР 5.3. Очевидно, этот код запускается на более старой версии.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
    require "libs/rb.php";

    $db = [
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=loc`введите сюда код`alhost;dbname=name;charset=utf-8',
    'user' => 'login',
    'pass' => 'password'
    ];

    R::setup($db['dsn'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);

?>
```